# How to get element index of a series

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with let's say 2 columns. Example below :

[image]

I want to match text from column "Text1" with values of column "Text2" and create a new column which says "matched" or "not matched" with position of column "Text2" where match found. Example shown below :

[image]

With my approach, I was able to do the match but I am not able to get the position of text in column "Text2" where the match is found. My approach is below :

```
df["Match?"] = df["Text1"].apply(lambda x: "matched" if x in df["Text2"].values else "not matched")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`

```
data = """txt1,txt2
hello,that
hi,these
sure,sure
there,hello
"""
df["Match?"] = df["txt1"].apply(lambda x: 
                                "Matched ,"+ str(*np.where(df["txt2"] == x)[0]) 
                                if np.where(df["txt2"] == x)[0].shape[0] != 0 
                                else "Unmatched" )
```

**Output:**

```
    txt1   txt2      Match?
0  hello   that  Matched ,3
1     hi  these   Unmatched
2   sure   sure  Matched ,2
3  there  hello   Unmatched
```